# LDAP login in grails 3.1.6. Error message "LDAP: error code 32"

Tags: ldap, grails-3.1

I am very new to the grails framework. I am using the given below configuration. While, I try to login, I am getting the error message "LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException".

```
Grails Version: 3.1.6
Groovy Version: 2.4.6
JVM Version: 1.8.0_92
```

Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE"
    **compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:3.0.1" 
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1"**
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.6"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}
```

Application.yml

```
grails:
   plugin:
      springsecurity:
         providerNames: ['ldapAuthProvider','anonymousAuthenticationProvider']
         ldap:
            context:
               managerDn: '[distinguishedName]'
               managerPassword: secret
               server: 'ldap://[ip]:[port]/'
            authorities:
               retrieveDatabaseRoles: true
            password:
               algorithm: 'SHA-256'
            search:
               base: [dc=mycompany,dc=com]
               filter: 'uid={0}'
               attributesToReturn: ['displayname','mail']
               searchSubtree: true
```

MyUserDetails.groovy

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

class MyUserDetails extends User {

   // extra instance variables
   final String fullname
   final String email
   final String title

   MyUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
         boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
         Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities, String fullname,
         String email, String title) {

      super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,
            accountNonLocked, authorities)

      this.fullname = fullname
      this.email = email
      this.title = title
   }
}
```

MyUserDetailsContextMapper.groovy

```
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.UserDetailsContextMapper

class MyUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

   UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
                                  Collection authorities) {

      String fullname = ctx.originalAttrs.attrs['name'].values[0]
      String email = ctx.originalAttrs.attrs['mail'].values[0].toString().toLowerCase()
      def title = ctx.originalAttrs.attrs['title']

      new MyUserDetails(username, null, true, true, true, true,
                        authorities, fullname, email,
                        title == null ? '' : title.values[0])
   }

   void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Only retrieving data from AD is currently supported")
   }
}
```

Error in console

```
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com'
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:183)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:376)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:328)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:629)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForMultipleAttributeValues(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:241)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleAttributeValues(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGroupMembershipRoles(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:238)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.userdetails.GrailsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGroupMembershipRoles(GrailsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.groovy:114)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3160)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1846)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1769)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:341)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$4.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:322)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:363)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Also, it would be helpful, if anyone shares the detailed step to configure LDAP in grails 3.1.6.

Thank You very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently converted a 2.x Grails app to 3.1.8 & moved my ldap config from groovy to yml. Not sure if the format is correct for some of your config, seems like you have lists for e.g. providerNames, I have split these out as follows:

```
springsecurity:
        active: true
        useSecurityEventListener: false
        providerNames:
            - ldapAuthProvider
            - anonymousAuthenticationProvider
        ldap:
            context:
                managerDn: 'cn=Directory Manager'
                managerPassword: 'secret'
                server: 'ldap://localhost:389'
            authorities:
                retrieveGroupRoles: true
                groupSearchBase: 'ou=Groups,dc=blah,dc=co,dc=uk'
            search:
                base: 'dc=blah,dc=co,dc=uk'
                searchSubtree: true
                attributesToReturn:
                    - mail
                    - name
            auth:
                hideUserNotFoundExceptions: false
        logout:
            postOnly: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I'm not sure what you are using for LDAP.  You might want to give ApacheDS a try, as it comes with an excellent ApacheDS Studio application that helps you build your LDAP hierarchy, test and debug.